# Select from multiple SQL Server 2008 databases not working

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, database-connection, multiple-databases

I'm trying to select from a few tables in different servers using SQL Server 2008. This is the script I'm using:

```
exec sp_addlinkedserver @server = '192.168.5.208'
select * from [192.168.5.208].[hrm2].[dbo].tb_mt_pim
```

but it doesn't work. It returns a message

> 'Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with windows authentication'

Can someone tell me why?

Comment: you need to add authentication, (login details for you server)

Comment: how? I don't see where I can add the authentication in sp_addlinkedserver from this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx

I also tried replacing the `exec sp_addlinkedserver @server = '192.168.5.208'` with `EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin '192.168.5.208', 'false', NULL, 'sa', 'Actsstsj4547'` but the error message stays the same

Answer (score 0):

Seems you not adding Authentication.

try:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin
@useself='FALSE',
@rmtsrvname='TEST_LINK',
@rmtuser='user',
@rmtpassword='secret'
```

Obviously edit the strings to your credentials and execute, should be able to connect then.